# Use PowerShell to establish a domaincontroller on the original forest

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to use PowerShell to establish a domaincontroller on the original forest.

The original forest "mysite.com" is a WindowsServer2008R2Forest.

I am working in windowsserver2008r2sp1.

I would like to incorporate this code in a PowerShell program to define a domaincontroller for original forest:

domaincontroller.ps1

```
 Import-Module ActiveDirectory
 Import-Module ServerManager
 Enable-PSRemoting -force  

 $DCPromoFile = 
@"
[DCINSTALL] 
UserDomain="mysite.com"
UserName="Administrator"  
Password="password1234"
ReplicaOrNewDomain="Replica"
ReplicaDomainDNSName="mysite.com"
DatabasePath="c:\Windows\NTDS" 
LogPath="c:\Windows\NTDS" 
SYSVOLPath="c:\Windows\SYSVOL"
InstallDNS="Yes"
CriticalReplicationOnly="No"
ConfirmGC="Yes"
SafeModeAdminPassword="password4321"
RebootOnCompletion="Yes"
"@ 
$DCPromoFile | out-file c:\folders\dcpromo.ini -force
```

Comment: ... and your problem is?

Comment: Found My own problem.  I needed to create a blank dcpromo.ini file.